# One Ajax call doesn't seem to work after being called

Tags: ajax

I have several ajax calls in my application and all of them work. However one of the calls doesn't seem to respond.

```
function GetList() {
    $.ajax({
        url: serviceURL + 'GetList',
        type: 'POST',
        dataType: 'json',
        contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
        success: function (data: Store[]) { GetListSuccess(data); },
        error: function (error: JQueryXHR) {
            OnError(error);
        }
    });

}
```

`GetList` is an stored procedure that I have in my Database. When I execute it through the application I get the following error.

> XMLHttpRequest: Network Error 0x2eff, Could not complete the operation
>   due to error 00002eff

I checked the web console and noticed that for this particular call my Type is 'Plain' instead of 'Json'.

Comment: So what do you see in the network panel. Is the call successful?

Comment: The call failed

Comment: Is there data to send? is all your ajax requests start in the same time?

Comment: I am not sending any data only receiving data from the data. The ajax call initiates after the login button is pressed.